# Как нарисовать фигуру в CSS?

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь использовать before (присовокупить кружок к прямоугольнику), но что-то не получается. Фигура - горизонтально расположенная спичка: слева - кружок 9х9, справа - прямоугольник 128х2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как видите, ничего сложного:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.match {
  position: relative;
  width: 128px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: brown;
}

.match::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -1px;
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<div class="match"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь есть хороший образец.

Comment: @fromillia, пожалуйста.